# Asp net core API - put method

Tags: asp.net, api, blazor-webassembly, put

I'm struggling to have the API PUT method working correctly while consuming my api (hosted on Plesk) from a blazor webassembly (.net6).

I Already have the GET and POST method working fine and already set my cors policy (`AllowAnyOrigins`,`AllowAnyMethod`,`AllowAnyHeader`) but still getting the error: `"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"` and `405` if i try directly in the web api (swagger).
Any ideas?

here is the reply from swagger:

allow: GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,TRACE,PUT,POST  content-length:
104  content-type: text/html  date: Thu,05 May 2022 12:29:43 GMT
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0  via: Proxy  x-firefox-spdy: h2  x-powered-by: ASP.NET  x-powered-by-plesk: PleskWin

request url

https://************.it/api/Requisitions/62

here is the controller:

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]  

    

public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateRequisitionAsync(int id, [FromBody] RequisitionDTO requisitionFromUI)
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    throw new BadHttpRequestException("Error in the requisition");
                }
                else
                {
                    var requisitionInDb = await _context.Requisitions.SingleOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Id == requisitionFromUI.Id);
                    if (requisitionInDb != null)
                    {
                        requisitionInDb.PriceCurr = requisitionFromUI.PriceCurr;
                        requisitionInDb.PurchaseQty = requisitionFromUI.PurchaseQty;
                        requisitionInDb.WantedReceiptDate = requisitionFromUI.WantedReceiptDate;
                        requisitionInDb.PartDescription = requisitionFromUI.PartDescription;
                        requisitionInDb.RequisitionNote = requisitionFromUI.RequisitionNote;
                        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return Ok(requisitionFromUI);
                    }
                    return NotFound();
                }
            }
```

in program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
{
    builder.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader();
}));

var app = builder.Build();
```

the request pipeline:

```
app.UseSwagger();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c => {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "myapi v1");
        c.RoutePrefix = String.Empty;
    });
}
else
{
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c => {});
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors("MyPolicy");

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but here goes what I think could help you. You need to add allowed list of headers to your reponse in your API's startup:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Content-Type, Accept, Request-Language, Request-Timezone");
});
```

Also, you need to specify origins you allow using the Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Either only the origin is allowed, or another domain can be allowed or any origin.

```
context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", originHeader);
```

Where context is your HttpContext. In the error message, or information message you get when your request is rejected because of preflight, it should tell you what header is not allowed.

Read here [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Also read here  [about Middleware delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

> browsers make a "preflight" request to the server hosting the
> cross-origin resource, in order to check that the server will permit
> the actual request. In that preflight, the browser sends headers that
> indicate the HTTP method and headers that will be used in the actual
> request.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it amending the web.config file as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
           <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
        </modules>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\RocketstarWebApiNext.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

bu I'd like to have Visual Studio generating the file correctly and not fixing this every API publish/modifications.